# Revenge downvoting?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I don't have a link to the question as it was deleted by its owner but I believer the asker did not like my answer and downvoted some of my other [questions and answers.](https://serverfault.com/users/62491/kce?tab=reputation) At least it seems mighty coincidental that after he deleted his original question I was downvoted on four questions immediately.

The question was deleted otherwise I would link it here (I would rather not publically link the user either). Is there a moderator I can refer this too? I believe that while I might of been short in my answers I was still courteous and patient - and the downvotes have little to do with quality of my answers/questions.

Comment: He didn't like your answer, and downvoted you? What did you say?  did you downvote the question as well? I thought you can not know who downvoted you, but maybe I just don't have the right rep to do.

Comment: He kept asking for how to install the "lib64 files" - to which I replied (with mounting curtness I must admit) that I needed more information to find out why his Debian box wouldn't boot. There was confusion about whether or not he deleted /sbin/init (again due to incomplete information) - where I basically said I didn't think he had the skill to diagnose what was actually broken, and that the quickest way to a working system would be a re-install. Within about 15 minutes, the question was deleted and I received a bunch of downvotes on other questions. Mighty coincidental if you ask me.

Comment: This just happened to me. http://meta.serverfault.com/q/5896/13716  What is with the negativity around here? The "shoot first" behavior hurts SF, IMO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The vote detection script hasn't shown anything yet, but that doesn't mean it won't. I don't know how regularly the script runs, but it's at least once every 24 hours. If you haven't got your rep back in 24 hours and you still believe you've been done wrong, just put a quick update to your question to say you've waited 24 hours.

Comment: I don't think 4 downvotes will trip the detector, though its around that level. In any case a quick upvote from one of us will more than compensate for your rep losses. ;)

Comment: Done, using an answer picked at random.

Comment: @John - I hope it was at least an answer worth of an upvote ;)

Comment: @Mark, it already had some otherwise I would have picked another.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers - it's cool, it was a bit tongue in cheek :)

Comment: I don't think it tripped the vote detection script - I think I'm a few rep points short of where I was on Friday, but I'm not terribly concerned about it. I do appreciate the compensation for my attempt to salvage the apparently un-salavageable (I'll just flag to close next time).